# not able to Click the Add New Case Button in selenium

Tags: selenium

not able to Click the Add New Case Button, we have 3 different server and one server its working by "value= Add New Case"

```
<div class="top-buttonbar">  
   <span class="p-btn-left"><span class="p-btn-right"><span class="p-btn-center">
      <button class="p-btn-text add" type="button" onclick="fnAddCase()" style="padding-left:3px">Add New Case</button>
   </span></span></span> 
   <span class="p-btn-left"><span class="p-btn-right"><span class="p-btn-center">
      <button class="p-btn-text add" type="button" onclick="fnAddPolicy()" style="padding-left:8px" title="Add Policy">Add Policy</button>
    </span></span></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="top-buttonbar">
<span class="p-btn-left"><span class="p-btn-right"><span class="p-btn-center"><button class="p-btn-text add" type="button" onclick="fnAddCase()" style="padding-left:3px">Add New Case</button></span></span></span>
<span class="p-btn-left"><span class="p-btn-right"><span class="p-btn-center"><button class="p-btn-text add" type="button" onclick="fnAddPolicy()" style="padding-left:8px" title="Add Policy">Add Policy</button></span></span></span>
</div>

Comment: How did you tried so far mention the code snippet and error as well

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the **Add New Case** button you can use the following line of code :

- Java :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top-buttonbar']/span[@class='p-btn-left']//button[@class='p-btn-text add' and contains(.,'Add New Case')]")).click();
  ```
- Python :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='top-buttonbar']/span[@class='p-btn-left']//button[@class='p-btn-text add' and contains(.,'Add New Case')]").click()
  ```

Comment: [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:48661/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]

Comment: getting above error after used below code
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top-buttonbar']/span[@class='p-btn-left']//button[@class='p-btn-text add' and contains(.,'Add New Case')]")).click()

Comment: Update the question with the current code trial and the full error stack trace.

Comment: am using below function
  public static void ClickANC()
  {
    PSBrowser.psSelenium().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top-buttonbar']/span[@class='p-btn-left']//button[@class='p-btn-text add' and contains(.,'Add New Case')]")).click();
       PSBrowser.psSelenium().findElementByXPath("//form[@name='inboxForm']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/span[1]/span/span/button").click();
       PSBrowser.psSelenium().findElementByCssSelector("input.Button[value*='Add New Case']").click();
     
  }